# Как правильно писать "средне мягкий матрас"

Tags: орфография

*Cредне мягкий матрас* - вместе или раздельно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В словаре "Слитно или раздельно?" М., "Русский язык", стр.689-691 все сложные слова с первой частью ***средне*** (их около 230) написаны слитно, в том числе ***среднетяжёлый***. Так что слово ***среднемягкий*** тоже  надо писать слитно.

***Пишутся слитно "прилагательные-термины, если первая часть начинается со слов мелко-, остро-, узко-, трудно-, высоко-, низко-, глубоко-, крупно-, сильно- и т.д.: остросюжетный, слабосолёный, мелкооптовый и др.***" [здесь](http://zelena6811.blogspot.ru/2014/12/1-13.html)

Answer (score 1):

Корректно:  среднемягкий матрац. Но лучше все же исправить на предложенный вам вариант: матрас средней мягкости.

средне... - первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно.

**См.: Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.**

Answer (score 0):

Матрас средней мягкости. 
(Отредактировал свой ответ, во избежании путаницы)

Comment: Вопрос как правильно писать средне мягкий матрас.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя большинство сложных слов на средне- пишутся слитно (среднесуточный, среднеспелый, среднеарифметический), термин "средне-мягкий" имеет дефисную форму написания, так как это именно терминология: матрасы по техническим параметрам делятся на мягкие, средне-мягкие, средне-жесткие и жесткие. Это реальная практика применения слова. Кроме того, термины нельзя заменить другим выражением.

В словаре Лопатина ("Слитно, раздельно или через дефис?" 2012 года) встречается похожий пример (также из области терминологии): средне-тяжелая болезнь.

Можно считать, что таким образом передается оттенок мягкости, поэтому используется дефисная форма.

Сравнить: До полудня лежала свинцово-тяжёлая обильная роса.Высокая трава испускает густой, приторно-медовый запах. В этих примерах через дефис пишутся оттенки физических свойств (не только цветов и чувств, как обычно).

Comment: В орфографическом словаре Лопатина, который я привел в своем ответе, среднетяжелый - слитно.